# I want to convert some hindi string into html entities through php

Tags: php, html

```
$message = "मैं हिंदी से एच टी एम एल टेक्स्ट में कनभर्ट करना चाहता हूँ ।";

$message_convert = SomeKindOfunctionOrProcess($message);

echo $message_convert;
```

output :

```
&#2350;&#2376;&#2306; &#2361;&#2367;&#2306;&#2342;&#2368; &#2360;&#2375;
&#2319;&#2330; &#2335;&#2368; &#2319;&#2350; &#2319;&#2354;
&#2335;&#2375;&#2325;&#2381;&#2360;&#2381;&#2335; &#2350;&#2375;&#2306;
&#2325;&#2344;&#2349;&#2352;&#2381;&#2335; &#2325;&#2352;&#2344;&#2366;
&#2330;&#2366;&#2361;&#2340;&#2366; &#2361;&#2370;&#2305; &#2404;
```

Comment: Does the output differ if you simply echo the message?

Comment: I did some reformatting to make the difference of input and desired output visible. Please check, especially the newlines I inserted (convinced that you wanted them, but puzzuled why the were not there...) If it is not as you want it you can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "मैं हिंदी से एच टी एम एल टेक्स्ट में कनभर्ट करना चाहता हूँ ।";
$message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
echo $message;
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  or are you looking for a real converter that converts hindi into html? because thats not possible i think.